# Projecting onto subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question**

> Find the orthogonal projection of
>   $$x = \begin{bmatrix}7 \\ 0 \\ -4 \\ -4 \end{bmatrix}$$
>   onto the subspace of $\mathbb R^4$ spanned by 
>   $$v_1 = \begin{bmatrix}-4 \\ 2 \\ 2 \\ -4 \end{bmatrix}, v_2 =\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 2 \\ 2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

**Answer**

So I projected $x$ onto $v_1$ and $v_2$ and got 
$x_{v1} = \begin{bmatrix}2 \\ -1 \\ -1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix} and, x_{v2} = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ respectively.

I then subtracted $x_{v1}$ and $x_{v2}$ from $x$ and got $\begin{bmatrix}4 \\ 0 \\ -4 \\ -6 \end{bmatrix}$

which is wrong, and the correct answer should be $\begin{bmatrix}3 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$

So what have I done wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to subtract these two things from $x$? Note that $x_{v1} + x_{v_2}$ is the expected answer. You seem to be calculating the component of $v$ which is orthogonal to the subspace in question.

Comment: Cheers mate, your right, i just got stuck in without properly reading the question.

Comment: @DylanMoreland Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).